# Spring Boot: workaround invalid client Accept header

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Recent versions of Prometheus send an invalid `q=2` value in the `Accept` header of scrape requests to `/actuator/prometheus`. See https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/13268. This results in a response of `406 Not Acceptable`, because Spring Boot fails to parse the `Accept` header properly.

Is there a way to workaround this issue until it is fixed upstream?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring WebFlux, a `WebFilter` can be used to modify the inbound request so that it is valid. Example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Component
class InvalidQValuesFilter : WebFilter {
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    val acceptHeader = exchange.request.headers[HttpHeaders.ACCEPT]
    if (acceptHeader?.any { it.contains("*/*;q=2") } == true) {
      exchange.request.mutate().headers { headers ->
        headers[HttpHeaders.ACCEPT] = acceptHeader.map {
          it.replace("*/*;q=2", "*/*;q=0.1")
        }
      }
    }

    return chain.filter(exchange)
  }
}
```